# Concatenate multiple rows in MySQL or PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to join multiple rows into a single one based on matching of two columns, the mid and the sub id.

| mid | parent | sub | org | item | price | dsc1 | dsc2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 216 |  |  | 1 | Apple |  |  |  |
| **217** | 216 |  | 1 | iPhone | $500 |  |  |
| 218 | 216 | **217** | 1 | iPhone PLUS | $600 |  |  |
| **219** | 216 |  | 1 | MacBook | $900 |  |  |
| 220 | 216 | **219** | 1 | MacBook Pro | $1200 |  |  |

I need this output, make note of the bold id's above, the item with null sub is base and the subtype comes after:

```
 Apple $500 iPhone $600 iPhone PLUS
 Apple $900 MacBook $1200 MacBook Pro
```

I tried with group concat but it doesn't work properly
https://phpize.online/?phpses=501d07429d08ce3d3092f555d9d6367a&sqlses=c40160db7e24f450d3055397db86aeda&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Another option is to display multiple rows as above and then concat with PHP if anyone knows how to do it:

```
select top.item, base.mid, base.sub, base.price, base.item from menu base, menu top 
where top.mid = base.parent and base.parent is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using MySQL self-joins:

```php
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->query("
SELECT
  `parent_menu`.`item` as `parent_item`,
  `menu`.`price`,
  `menu`.`item`,
  `sub_menu`.`price` as `sub_item_price`,
  `sub_menu`.`item` as `sub_item`
FROM
    `menu`
-- Join the parent brands in if there are any
JOIN
    `menu` as `parent_menu`
ON
    `menu`.`parent` = `parent_menu`.`mid`
-- Join in the subs
JOIN
    `menu` as `sub_menu`
ON
    `menu`.`mid` = `sub_menu`.`sub`");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo implode(' ', $row) . "\n";
}
```

[Try Me Online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=a3fe5aa13158ca5362188032331cbafa&sqlses=3d9ea2a6c6585ca6e48621a745aa3867&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)

Explanation:

Our main select statement is intended to select the mids, iPhone and MacBook.

All of the mids have a parent, so we can inner join the `menu` table back in where the `parent` field in the main table is equal to the `mid` field in the parent menu join. This gives us the menu_item values (Brand names) for each of the mids.

We can then do another inner-join on the menu table to select for the sub item prices and names.

Finally, by selecting `\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, we will get an array which looks like this:

```
[
  'parent_item' => 'Apple',
  'price' => '$500',
  'item' => 'iPhone ',
  'sub_item_price' => '$600',
  'sub_item' => 'iPhone Plus',
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Some entries have only the base product while others might have 3 or more subtypes. I think with this code it doesn't work - I had something similar... https://phpize.online/?phpses=a3fe5aa13158ca5362188032331cbafa&sqlses=f672247eb0e7dfcc6889a97e7a906bc1&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: for instance this group_concat is working somewhat good but it's ignoring categories which have only one product and I cannot solve it\
`select top.item, group_concat(concat(base.price,' '), base.item, concat(sub.price,' '), sub.item separator ''), base.dsc1, base.dsc2 from menu sub 
 join menu base on sub.sub = base.mid 
 join menu top on sub.parent = top.mid
where base.mid=sub.sub group by top.item, base.item`

Comment: @stefan999 In that case, you'd probably have better luck with splitting the query into two or three separate ones for each level, or considering a different database schema that wouldn't require recursive self-joins.

But if recursive self-joins are required, you can find more info on how to do that in this thread https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46127/recursive-self-joins

Comment: Actually, if it's only 3 levels deep, you could do something like this:
https://phpize.online/?phpses=9b7f034d83e84a03af29959793c18d45&sqlses=f672247eb0e7dfcc6889a97e7a906bc1&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: It's good, however the 2nd row is a duplicate - $900 iPhone red should be 3rd item or last item in the 1st row... Can you try with the code above (i cannot figure out what i am missing in my code)

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment:

I cannot see how the following data set accords with what you've posted above.

```
+=====+========+========+=====+=============+========+========+========+
| mid | parent | sub    | org | item        | price  | dsc1   | dsc2   |
+=====+========+========+=====+=============+========+========+========+
| 1   | (null) | (null) | 1   | Apple       | (null) | (null) | (null) |
+-----+--------+--------+-----+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 2   | 1      | (null) | 1   | iPhone      | $1000  | (HI)   | (null) |
+-----+--------+--------+-----+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 3   | 1      | 2      | 1   | iPhone Plus | $1221  | (HI)   | (null) |
+-----+--------+--------+-----+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 4   | 1      | 2      | 1   | iPhone Red  | $1600  | (HI)   | (null) |
+-----+--------+--------+-----+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
| 5   | 1      | (null) | 1   | iMac        | $900   | (HI)   | (null) |
+-----+--------+--------+-----+-------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: So it's a 3-level data. 1st level - 1st row is a category (has not parent id), 2nd level is basic product level (parent id corresponds to mid of the category), 3rd level is a variety of a basic product (identified by not null sub id which corresponds to mid of the basic product)

Comment: But there is no '216' in the above data set